# Scala: What is wrong with my method?

Tags: scala

I have a method `fun`. It takes a function literal as a parameter and return `Int`.

```
def fun(arg: (Int) => Int): Int = {
  val ret = 5 * arg + 10
  ret
}
```

It represent a function `f(x) = 5x+10`, which could take a parameter as another function (i.g. `g(x) = x+1)`, so `f(g(2)) = 5(2+1)+10 = 25`

But my Scala code doesn't compile. Why?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: You're not calling the function parameter, and you're not passing a function either. Notice that `f(g(2))` is equivalent to `f(3)`. You want a simple `Int` parameter, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is a functional programming language, it has a very nice feature where we can pass functions as arguments, to store them in variables, and to return them from other functions.

```
object FunctionCalc{
      def f(Input: Int => Int) : Int ={
        val temp = 10

        (Input(5) + temp ) // It takes functions as input which take input as Int and return Int. 
      }

      def f(Input:Int) :Int ={
        Input + 4 //overloaded function

      }
      def g(arg : Int) :Int= {
        arg+1 //adding 1
      }

      def h(arg:Int) : Int ={
        arg+3 //adding 3
    } 
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
       println( f(g(2)))
       println(f(h(4)))
       println(f(6))
      }
    }
```

Consider the above example we are passing functions g and h as inputs to f().

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using function "arg:Int=>Int" as and argument in your code.

"arg" is a function you can use it like this.

```
def g(x:Int) = x+1
def f(arg:Int=>Int)(y:Int) = 5* arg(y) + 10

scala> f(g)(2)
res23: Int = 25
```